# program a GET function to repeat over time, saving data with different names

Tags: r, api, loops, automation

I am working with an API that updates their data every 5 seconds. I want my code to repeat every minute to get different files with data updated data. Making it loop is not enough, I need to get each file to be saved with a different name (data1, data2, data3...). I have not been able to find a good way of doing that.

```
    url<-(API URL)
    res=GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))

    result<-xmlParse(file = res)
    node<-xmlRoot(result)
```

That's the code I need to replicate and save in different files, so I would need the names of res, result and node to change every time the code is ran by the timed loop.

Comment: How are you running the timed loop? Is it in R or you are doing it externally?

Comment: I'm doing it in R. I am not sure what the best way of running the loop would be. Regarding the changing names, I was wondering if I could set them to name themselves after the time they were ran like res(time) (e.g. res1150. res1151, res1152...).

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the loop code?

Comment: I haven't coded that yet... I new at coding. I was reading about using cron to schedule it every minute, unless there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the current date and time as filename while writing the data to csv so that the file is unique everytime.

```
url<-(API URL)
res=GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))
result<-xmlParse(file = res)
node<-xmlRoot(result)
write.csv(node, sprintf('file_%s.csv', Sys.time()), row.names = FALSE)
```

You may use cron to run this script at any interval.

Comment: Hi, I am using cron and works well, but I am struggling with the sprintf function. I get the following error:                                                  
             In sprintf("'file_%s.csv',  :
  one argument not used by format 'file_%s.csv'

Comment: Are you sure the brackets are properly closed? What is the exact code that you are using?

Comment: They were properly closed. Anyways, I tried another function and it worked. Thank you anyways!